# Firebase site not found error when navigating directly into subdirectories

Tags: url-routing, vue-router, firebase-hosting

I have a single-page app hosted on Firebase, built using `vue-cli` v3. Most of its routing is done using `vue-router`.

The app works fine when users navigate to its home page and navigate around using the links within. Problem arise when a user navigates into a subdirectory using address bar or links from outside.

The app is located here: https://www.amborjo.com.

Here's a sample of the problem: https://www.amborjo.com/covid-19

And here's relevant parts of `firebase.json`

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source":
          "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "predeploy.sh"
    ],
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: It looks like I have to re-add my custom domains to Firebase. They had disappeared for some reason.